# Having trouble writing stack implementation c++

Tags: c++, casting, stack

I am building a programming language interpreter, and I am currently working on writing the stack code. Write now the stack will only hold byte values, but it will be extended to hold other bytes as well. At the moment I am having trouble with casting between 'BaseObject' that all my stack objects extend and my `jbyte` class. Here is my current test code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

class BaseObject
{
public:
    virtual string getIdentifier(){return "Not Implemented";}
};

class Stack
{
    class jbyte : public BaseObject
    {
    private:
        INT8 byteValue;

    public: 
        jbyte(INT8 value)
        {
            byteValue = value;
        }

        INT8 getValue()
        {
            return byteValue;
        }
    };

private:
    stack<BaseObject> objectStack;

public:
    void pushByte(INT8 byteValue)
    {
        jbyte toPush(byteValue);
        objectStack.push(toPush);
    }

    INT8 popByte()
    {
        if(objectStack.size() == 0)
        {
            cout<<"ERROR: Trying To Pop Value From Empty Stack\nPress Any Key To Continue...";
            _gettch();
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            BaseObject& bo = objectStack.top();
            jbyte& b = dynamic_cast<jbyte&>(bo);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Stack stack;
    stack.pushByte(9);
    stack.popByte();
    while(true);
}
```

When I try to run this however, I get an `Unhandled exception at at 0x75C4C41F` in StackTests.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_cast at memory location 0x0034F858.

I would like to know how to fix this problem, or if that is difficult, how I could rewrite the stack to work successfully.

Comment: `std::stack<INT8> st;` Done. And an interesting mechanism you have there for "pausing" at the end of `main()`. That said, you need to better understand what `dynamic_cast` does.

Comment: but that could only hold bytes, what if i wanted to be able to store int on the stack instead

Comment: So you want to hold an object *and* a byte attached to it? Is that correct? (And if it is, do you know what object slicing is)?

Comment: no, i just want to be able to hold a stack of objects of unrelated types in a class object representing a stack, i dont know what object slicing is

Comment: Ah,i c. well then, unless you're using something like a `boost::any` you're somewhat out of luck. Blindly casting a  "value" to "bytes" and back is not going to work like you think it will.

Comment: well, how should i write my stack class

Comment: Start by defining exactly what you need it to do. If you need it to store some *single* arbitrary object type, thats easy. If it needs to hold *anything*,  that's *hard*.

Comment: Your `jbyte` is being sliced when putting it into `objectStack`. Store pointers to the objects in `objectStack` and it won't slice.

Comment: In C++ containers like this are usually implemented as templates, so that the type of object they hold can be specified by the user rather than hard-coded by the container implementation.  If a given Stack object only needs to store one kind of value, tempting your Stack class is definitely the way to go.   (and even if you want to store multiple different types of item in a single Stack object, templating Stack will still let you do that, as you could template it to store e.g. shared_ptr objects)

Answer (score 0):

When you `objectStack.push(toPush)`, the `jbyte` part of `toPush` is sliced off and only the `BaseObject` part remains. That's why casting the `BaseObject` back to `jbyte` is no longer possible.